# Different header referer than document.referrer

Tags: javascript, html

this is my request header:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3002
Connection: keep-alive
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Google Chrome";v="96"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
Accept: */*
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:5500
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:5500/new.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
If-None-Match: W/"c-Lve95gjOVATpfV8EL5X4nxwjKHE"
```

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3002/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:3002
Referrer Policy: unsafe-url
```

and my console returns for document.referrer and location.href:

```
document.referrer
'http://127.0.0.1:5500/test.html'
location.href
'http://127.0.0.1:5500/new.html'
```

test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="referrer" content="unsafe-url"/>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="/new.html" target="_blank"  referrerpolicy="unsafe-url">test</a>

</html>
```

new.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="referrer" content="unsafe-url"/>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        setTimeout(() =>{
            console.log(fetch("http://localhost:3002/"))
        }, 4000)
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

as you can see the header referer is different then document.referrer, it is even possible to get referer from previous page and set it into referer header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as you can see the header referer is different then document.referrer

Because you are asking for the referrer in different documents which the browser was referred to by different documents.

The browser is asking for `/` because `new.html` told it to ask for it. The referer is `new.html`.

> it is even possible to get referer from previous page and set it into referer header?

No. You cannot make the browser lie about what referred it.